# Allow customer to login only if they accept terms & condition

Tags: magento2, login

Allow user to access his account only if accept Terms and Condition on its first log in.
Sign in the agreement copy with the name or email id.

Can any one tell me how can I achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this functionality by Put a Terms and Conditions checkbox on the register form.

Put below code in your customer register form template file (Phtml File)

```
<div style="width: auto; margin: 0;" class="field choice newsletter">
        <input type="checkbox" data-validate="{required:true}" name="custom-terms" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Terms & conditions') ?>" id="register-input-custom" class="checkbox">
        <label for="custom-terms" class="label">
            <span>
                <?php echo __('I have read and accept the ') ?><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('privacy_policy');?>"><?php echo __('PRIVACY POLICY') ?></a><?php echo __(' and ') ?><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('terms_conditions');?>"><?php echo __('CONDITIONS OF USE') ?></a>
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: thx. But i want to make them right there name or email id. That too for first login only. Hope you might have seen EULA